# observeEvent ignoreInit not working with flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

In Shiny - flexdashboard, 
I am using `observeEvent` with `ignoreInit=TRUE` in two cases. One with `eventExpr` that is the input directly and one where it is wrapped with an `eventReactive`. The first `observeEvent` below (corresponding to the `react` input) does not print anything on start of the app. The second one (corresponding to the `input` input) does. Both have `ignoreInit=TRUE`. Is there an explanation for this? I couldn't find any.

````
---
title: "observeEvent ignoreInit"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
```

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
### A

```{r}

checkboxInput(inputId = "input", label = "input")
checkboxInput(inputId = "react", label = "react")

reactBoxreac = eventReactive(input$react, {input$react})

observeEvent(reactBoxreac(), {
  print("observeEvent of react checkBox is executed\n")
}, ignoreInit=TRUE)

observeEvent(input$input, {
  print("observeEvent of input checkBox is executed\n")
}, ignoreInit=TRUE)

```
````

Comment: rename `input` to something else such as `checkboxInput(inputId = "input_data", label = "input")`

Comment: right, it's clearer but that's doesn't change the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, you should avoid having variables named `input`

````
---
title: "observeEvent ignoreInit"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
```

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
### A

```{r}

checkboxInput(inputId = "input_data", label = "input")
checkboxInput(inputId = "react", label = "react")

reactBoxreac = eventReactive(input$react, {input$react})

observeEvent(reactBoxreac(), {
  print("observeEvent of react checkBox is executed\n")
}, ignoreInit=TRUE)

observeEvent(input$input_data, {
  print("observeEvent of input checkBox is executed\n")
}, ignoreInit=TRUE)

```
````